# Set an Android Studio package as source

Tags: android-studio

For some reason my only package / folder is set as `androidTest` in `AndroidStudio` and I can't seem to set it as `source` like in IntelIJ via the `Project Structure`.

How may I set it as source?

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the folder, and using the "Mark Directory As" option?

Comment: This option does not seem to be displayed.

Comment: Try scrolling down a bit. Its usually the second last option.